# Determine if library file is referenced anywhere in SharePoint

Tags: document-library

Is it possible to determine if a library item is being referenced anywhere in SharePoint? We're doing cleanup at the root of our site collection and noticed a lot of items in the Site Assets library. We'd like to delete them but don't want to check every page in every site. Anyone know of a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest rename the files with a specific pattern like prefix "temp_" or suffix "*temp" and run a report for broken links: http://splinkchecker.codeplex.com/ (DISCLAIMER: I have not used this tool). Make an inventory of broken links and rename the files  so that there are no broken links. then delete the remaining temp** or *_temp files.

Renaming to temp files, restoring to original names based on broken link inventory and deleting remaining files requires some scripting or console app.

Answer (score 2):

I'd delete them and if people complain about 404s or things breaking, the pages can be inspected and the appropriate resources recovered from the recycle bin.  Or you could move eveything to a separate library instead ofdeleting it.  If things break then they can be recovered for a longer period of time from the separate library and after a set amount of days, the library could be deleted.

Also take a site backup prior to the move and retain it if you need to restore it to recover something.